# Web page is crawled by Google before its loaded

Tags: web, search, web-crawler, seo, search-engine

I have a website that I'm working on, and I'm trying to improve SEO. The website has a main page that loads content based on user location, and it takes a split second for a content to load. But I'm worried that crawling bots are not waiting for page to load and index an empty page. Whats the best way to tackle this?

Comment: What evidence do you ave that this is actually happening?

Comment: Those content pages are not showing up in Google. Also, all sitemap crawling services return empty result.

Comment: Also, google search console has no mentioning of the pages with content

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Google's [Fetch As Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) to see how Google sees your content. 
The Fetch as Google tool enables you to test how Google crawls or renders a URL on your site. You can use Fetch as Google to see whether Googlebot can access a page on your site, how it renders the page, and whether any page resources (such as images or scripts) are blocked to Googlebot. This tool simulates a crawl and render execution as done in Google's normal crawling and rendering process, and is useful for debugging crawl issues on your site.

Also, Make sure you aren't blocking Javascript from Search Engines.